# Как вывести в одну строчку?

Tags: python

```
X = (
    'A very looooooong wooooord',
    'Loremia ipsumia dolaria sitia ameti',
    'Have you ever been to Lituania ?',
    'Anyone who reads Old and Middle',
    'English literary texts will be familiar',
    'with the mid-brown volumes of the EETS,',
    'with the symbol of Alfreds jewel embossed on the front cover+'
)

for i in X:
    i = i.split()
    for z in i:
        if len(z) > 6:
            z = z[0:6] + "*"
        print(z)
```

Длинные слова нужно обрезать и поставить * в конце слова, print(z) выводит всё как надо, только по слову в каждую новую строчку, как сделать так, что бы выводило на примере X?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать регулярное выражение. В таком случае можно добиться, чтобы у длинных слов не обрезались знаки препинания, например.

```
import re
result = tuple(re.sub(r"\b([-\w]{6})\w+\b",r"\1*",line) for line in X)
print(*result, sep="\n")
```

Регулярное выражение r"\b([-\w]{6})\w+\b" означает:

\b   граница слова;

(  ) группирует выражение и возвращает найденный текст;

[..] один из символов в скобках ([^..] — любой символ, кроме тех, что в скобках);

**-**    задает один символ, который не должен быть в скобках;

\w   любая цифра или буква (\W — все, кроме буквы или цифры);

{6}  указывается число повторений предыдущего символа;

**+**    1 и более вхождений шаблона слева

То есть, взять отдельное слово; выделить в нем первые 6 символов, причем один может быть не буквой и не цифрой; выделенную группу не трогать, остальное для замены; так для каждого слова.

Регулярное выражение r"\1*" означает:

экранируем символ * одна штука, так как
***   это 0 и более вхождений шаблона слева

**re.sub(pattern, repl, string)**, где:
pattern - искомый шаблон;
repl - подстрока замены;
string - обрабатываемая строка;

Ищет шаблон в строке и заменяет его на указанную подстроку. Если шаблон не найден, строка остается неизменной.

Comment: эхх... через эту магию все короче получается :(, надо ее наконец толком выучить: `print(re.sub(r"\b([-\w]{6})\w+\b",r"\1*", ' '.join(X)))`

Answer (score 1):

Вот полный код:

```
X = (
    'A very looooooong wooooord',
    'Loremia ipsumia dolaria sitia ameti',
    'Have you ever been to Lituania ?',
    'Anyone who reads Old and Middle',
    'English literary texts will be familiar',
    'with the mid-brown volumes of the EETS,',
    'with the symbol of Alfreds jewel embossed on the front cover+'
)

for i in X:
    i = i.split()
    for z in i:
        if len(z) > 6: z = z[0:6] + "*"  
        print(z, end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
X = (
    'A very looooooong wooooord',
    'Loremia ipsumia dolaria sitia ameti',
    'Have you ever been to Lituania ?',
    'Anyone who reads Old and Middle',
    'English literary texts will be familiar',
    'with the mid-brown volumes of the EETS,',
    'with the symbol of Alfreds jewel embossed on the front cover+'
)

[print(*[(z[0:6] + "*") if len(z) > 6 else z for z in i.split()], sep='\n') for i in X]
```

можно чуть покороче

```
[print(*[(z, z[:6] + "*")[len(z) > 6] for z in i.split()], sep='\n') for i in X]
```

или так:

```
[print(*[(z, f"{z[:6]}*")[len(z) > 6] for z in i.split()], sep='\n') for i in X]
```

**Ой, не правильно понял задачу - надо было САМ ВЫВОД сделать в одну строчку :)**

тогда так:

```
[print(*[(z, z[:6] + "*")[len(z) > 6] for z in i.split()], sep=' ', end=' ') for i in X]
```

в общем в `print()` необходимо `end=' '` добавить

а можно обойтись и без атрибутов для `print()`:

```
print(' '.join(' '.join((z, z[:6] + "*")[len(z) > 6] for z in i.split()) for i in X))
```

**а вот самый короткий вариант решения:**

```
print(' '.join((z, z[:6] + "*")[len(z) > 6] for z in ' '.join(X).split()))
```

хотя нет, вот еще короче:

```
print(' '.join(z[:6] + "*" * (len(z) > 6) for z in ' '.join(X).split()))
```

**P.S.**

украл код у @GrAnd - решение через регулярки:

```
print(re.sub(r"\b([-\w]{6})\w+\b",r"\1*", ' '.join(X)))
```

Comment: Ну да, у меня подлиннее; зато немного понятнее ;)

Comment: ну просто в теме попросили "в одну строчку" или я не так понял? надо было именно вывод сделать в одну строчку - тогда ой, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Вы не поняли)))

Comment: Надо слова из одной фразы писать в одну строчку

Comment: А у него в коде каждое слово на отдельной строке

Comment: да, да, я уже исправил :)

Comment: ага, вот так да, должно сработать)

Comment: сделал кажется самый короткий вариант :)

Comment: ага, а у меня самый длинный ;) зато понятный

Comment: Вы прямо вундеркинд какой-то! Скоро, небось, найдёте решение в три символа :)

Comment: GrAnd его уже нашел - через регулярки (я их плохо знаю) - `print(re.sub(r"\b([-\w]{6})\w+\b",r"\1*", ' '.join(X)))`